# Mule ESB implementation guide

Tags: mule-studio

I have two databases on both MYSQL and sqlserver database engine , I want to connect with MULE ESB. The wanted result is a table with fields (MACC, tencc, ngaysinh) on MYSQL and a table with fields (ID, NAME, ADDRESS) on SQLSERVER, when I perform adding  manipulation (NAME, ADDRESS) on MYSQL, then the data also changes on SQLSERSER.
Thanks.

Comment: So what's your question then? I would recommend having a read of [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article in the Help Centre.

Answer (score 0):

Mule JDBC connectivity suites provide very good connectors for `mysql` and `sqlserver` databases.

For your requirement kindly go thorough Mulesoft official Document [here.](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/newbie/working-with-databases-jdbc-in-mule-studio/) and learn how to connect databases.

Good tutorial for `sqlserver` connectivity in mulesoft, [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/10/09/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-mulesoft/).

Based on above tutorial you can design you mule flow which connects to `mysql db` and `sqlserver db` using mule `timer` component, this timer component triggers event which reads data from `mysql` table and populate in `sqlserver` table as per need.

**Note :** In my opinion replicating data in such manner is not good design.  If its for PoC or for learning purpose its good. If possible can you please share your usecase.